# Change default workspace in Octave

Tags: ubuntu, octave

I freshly installed Octave on my Computer and was wondering if I could switch the default workspace from `/home/user` to, let's say, `/home/user/Octave` but could not find any advice online... I am using Ubuntu 14.04 if that's of any importance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I believe that this question is not SO material. This website is for programming questions only. Besides, you can get a way better help from [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/), for example.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will keep it in mind for next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an .octaverc file in your /home/user and add any initialization commands you want, in your example "cd ~/Octave". Btw, there is a very active mailing list for octave: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/help-octave.

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I needed. I wish I could upvote, unfortunately I have not yet received enough reputation.